# Webdriver/FXDriver utils.js causing 'unresponsive script' error in Firefox

Tags: javascript, testing, watir, webdriver, watir-webdriver

I've got some browser tests that run using Watir webdriver and FXDriver and things are generally working ok. However there is one test that loads a lightbox that contains a lot of HTML, and when the tests open this lightbox, Firefox shows a popup complaining that Utils.js line 432 from FXDriver has become an 'unresponsive script' and the test times out. I would rather fix the problem properly than extend the `dom.max_script_run_time` value, so I looked at the line in question...

```
goog.string.canonicalizeNewlines = function(a) {
  return a.replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n)/g, "\n")
};
```

It's pretty obvious why this is making Firefox hang, the question is how to stop it. This function gets called from many places, and because it gets called by Watir in a firebug-less Firefox instance it is pretty tricky to debug. How can I stop this from happening?

Editing the file, extending the timeout and reducing the amount of HTML it has to deal with are *not* options.

Comment: What is FXDriver? Google does not find anything that looks like a testing tool.

Comment: I'm trying to work out exactly why it gets used, but it seems to be used by the Watir webdriver.

Comment: What is your Ruby code doing at the point where this hangs?

Comment: It's looking to find wether an element exists in the DOM, I don't have access to the code ATM but will get it soon...

Comment: I get the similar issues with FF running on Win7. It is not Ruby problem, as I use Selenium2 Grid so it doesn't know which client is connecting to selenium node (in my case it is Java). Additionally I get sometimes errors in other lines of FXDriver. This and other issues (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=565541 and https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=566671) will make me stop using FF for testing.

Answer (score 2):

Start Watir-WebDriver with Firebug enabled.

First download the Firebug XPI file, then:

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile.add_extension "../path/to/firebug.xpi"
b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => profile
```

see: http://watirwebdriver.com/firefox/

Comment: Unfortunately the script with the problem (file:///C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20110927-6156-1unl25x/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/resource/modules/utils.js) does not appear in the list of JS files when FireBug is running, as I guess it gets injected by webdriver.